# How to initialize a List<T> property in Mock Object?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have the following code in my `[TestInitialize]` block and am trying to initialize a `List<T>` property on my object.

```
[TestClass]
public class MyTest
{
    private MyClass myClass;
    private Mock<myClassA> mockMyClassA;
    private List<Mock<myClassB>> mockMyClassB; //OK

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Setup()
    {
        mockMyClassA = new Mock<myClassA>();
        mockMyClassB = new List<Mock<myClassB>>(); //OK


        myClass = new MyClass
        {
            MyClassA = mockMyClassA.Object,
            MyClassB = mockBenefitsCoordination //None of this works
            {
                new Mock<mockMyClassB>()
                    {
                        //PropertyValue = mock??                            
                    }                    
            }
        }
```

The error I get is:

```
Cannot convert source type 'System.Collections.Genric.List<Moq.Mock<MyClassB>>' to target type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<MyClassB>>'
```

OK I see `List<T> to  IList<T>` issue. `MyClassB` is a `IList<T>`. I've tried changing it to no success. Basically I think I have the whole syntax for getting that List property configured with Moq. Does anyone know how to properly configure this?

Comment: I don't know Moq by heart (have most my experience with rhino-mocks), but can Moq generate mocks for classes? And what are you trying to do with `new List<Mock<myClassB>>`? Don't you just want to store a list with objects of `myClassB`, which in this case will be mock objects? Because then the interface would still be `List<myClassB>` (only I think you should have something like `List<IMyClassB>`)

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to initialize the list with the mock. You want to do the list initialization with the concrete object and add the mocked objects to that list.

Something like

```
private List<myClassB> myClassBList;
myClassBList.Add(new Mock<myClassB>.Object);
```